# POSTing/Sending Credit Card information to Magento from different app

Tags: php, plugins, magento, e-commerce, credit-card

Hey guys,
Is it possible to POST CC information to Magento from another store to magento so it can process the payment? In other words, are there any existing plugins or core functionality that allows for that? Thanks!

Comment: would the customers have accounts on the Magento server or would they all be Guest checkouts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely feasible, but not an existing function.  If you refer to my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627036/skip-checkout-in-magento-for-a-downloadable-product/5063574#5063574), you'll see the skeleton of how to achieve this.  You would create a controller that accepts the POST data and populates a Onepage model and saves it to create an Order.  That example is trivially easier since it's for Free Virtual products, so billing and shipping info and cost are not required, but you get the idea.

It would require a lot of validation and error handling, not to mention security and ensuring that you maintain PCI compliance.

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of Magento 1.5+ have the ability to add items to the cart via the API now, not exactly what your looking for but will at least put the end user in the cart and a product in their cart to begin checking out...

**Release Notes - Magento 1.5.0.0-beta1 (January 13, 2011)**

> Implemented SOAP Api calls for
>   shopping cart

http://www.magentocommerce.com/download/release_notes

Answer (score 0):

No.  You'd have to hack and/or build something up special