# Disable Checkout in Magento for a downloadable product

Tags: magento

Does anyone know of a way to create a free downloadable product which bypasses the checkout altogether? I have noticed that there is a 'free sample' option for downloadable products, but I would prefer not to use this if I can as I plan to use this field for its intended purpose when I add paid products.

I want:

1. to know if it is possible to create a downloadable product in Magento which doesn't require users to go through the usual checkout process (since it is free)
2. and which is not the 'Free Sample' field of a downloadable product**strong text**

Answer (score 0):

There's no way you can achieve your goal without code customization. You can try to find answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627036/skip-checkout-in-magento-for-a-downloadable-product), since it's similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your list.phtml template:

```
<?php
$_myprodlinks = Mage::getModel('downloadable/link');
$_myLinksCollection = $_myprodlinks->getCollection()->addProductToFilter($_product->getId());
if (sizeof($_myLinksCollection)>0):
foreach ($_myLinksCollection as $_link):
$mediaUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
$_linkpath = $mediaUrl."downloadable/files/links".$_link->getLinkFile();
?>
    <a href="<?php echo $_linkpath ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $this->__('Download') ?></a>
<?php
 endforeach;
endif;
?>
```

And make sure to give 777 permissions to media folder in your Magento root.

Let me know if this works for you.

Im not sure if this is the best way, but it works, you should know that this files are going to be accesible for all.