# How to skip the checkout process in magento?

Tags: magento

I am new to magento. I want skip the checkout process for magento downloadable product.

In my magento store, I have 4 products named as,

- **Freemium**
- **Standard**
- **Super**
- **Ultimate**

If the customer select the freemium product skip the checkout page and redirect it to the `downloadable/customer/products` with the count of the product. And place the order in order table too.

Help me to solve this issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: pls check this thread for the solutions..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627036/skip-checkout-in-magento-for-a-downloadable-product