# How to place an order with out billing and shipping address in magento downloadable product?

Tags: magento

In my store, I have one problem. Now, I have **downloadable products** only. How to make an order with out **billing** and **shipping** address in magento.

Because many of our customer feel bad about to fill the **billing** and **shipping** address for the **downloadable products**. Help me to solve this issue.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627036/skip-checkout-in-magento-for-a-downloadable-product. This seem to do what you are trying to accomplish