# Skipping Checkout Steps

Tags: php, magento

I implemented magento as an internal webshop of an organization. The shipping, billing and payment informations are same for all orders (and they will be automatically filled in by `LDAP`). Thus, I want to skip the first 4 checkout steps and to land on order "review".

I've already looked at the classes:

```
Controller/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
Model/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php
```

But I couldn't find, which Method is triggered by the button `proceed the checkout`.

How can I realize it?

Comment: Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627036/skip-checkout-in-magento-for-a-downloadable-product

Comment: Thank u for your answer. But I took a look it before I posted my question. I had already tried to modify this solution but I had no success. I tried to skip from "billing" to "review" by changing this part in all relevant areas:
    $this->loadLayout('checkout_onepage_review');
    $result['goto_section'] = 'review';
    $result['update_section'] = array(
                     'name' => 'review',
               'html' => $this->_getReviewHtml()
   );
 
It doesn't work. I would be very grateful if someone can show me a detailed code sample. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since what you're trying to accomplish  is not the default magento checkout workflow, you could try creating your own custom checkout programmatically, this way you will have total control and bypass the complicity of the onepage checkout.

See  [Programmatically create order in Magento](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programmatically-create-order-in-magento/)